# PyQt5 rotation pixmap

Tags: pyqt5, rotation, qpixmap

In Pyqt5 I want to rotate a pixmap but every time i tried it changes the size.
My code is:

```
import math
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QPointF, Qt, QRectF,QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QTransform, QPainter

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.arch1 = QPixmap("arch1.png")
        pm = QPixmap(556,556)
        rectF = QRectF(0,0,556,556)

        painter = QPainter(pm)
        painter.drawPixmap(rectF, self.arch1, rectF)
        painter.end()

        self.label = QLabel("AAAAAAAAAA")
        self.label.setPixmap(pm)
        butA = QPushButton("A")
        butA.clicked.connect(lambda: self.rotate_item())

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(butA)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def rotate_item(self):
        rectF = QRectF(0,0,556,556)
        self.arch1 = self.arch1.transformed(QTransform().rotate(36))
        pix = QPixmap(556,556)
        painter = QPainter(pix)
        painter.drawPixmap(rectF, self.arch1,QRectF(self.arch1.rect()))
        painter.end()
        self.label.setPixmap(pix)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I want only rotate not resize. What do you suggest me to do?
I have four other files and i want to rotate differently. i post some photos to understand what i want to do.

any other way to do this?

Circle one

[image: circle one]

Circle two

[image: circle two]

Complete circle

[image: complete circle]

Comment: Please be more careful when editing posts, as your recent modification made it completely unreadable, so I had to roll it back. Also always check the preview of the posts before submitting and read more about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the rotated pixmap has a bigger *bounding* rectangle.

Consider the following example:

[image: rotation and bounding rectangle]

The light blue square shows the actual bounding rectangle of the rotated image, which is bigger.

Using `drawPixmap(rectF, self.arch1, QRectF(self.arch1.rect()))` will cause to painter to draw the pixmap in the rectangle `rectF`, using the *new* bounding rectangle as source, so it becomes "smaller".

Instead of rotating the image, you should rotate the painter. Since transformations by default use the origin point of the painter (`0, 0`), we need first to translate to the center of the rectangle, rotate the painter, and then retranslate back to the origin.

Note that in the following example I'm also *always* drawing starting from the *source* image, without modifying it: continuously applying a transformation will cause drawing artifacts due to aliasing, and after some rotation the quality would be very compromised.
The `rotation` variable is to keep track of the current rotation.

```py
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        self.rotation = 0

    def rotate_item(self):
        self.rotation = (self.rotation + 36) % 360
        rectF = QRectF(0,0,556,556)
        pix = QPixmap(556,556)
        painter = QPainter(pix)
        painter.translate(rectF.center())
        painter.rotate(self.rotation)
        painter.translate(-rectF.center())
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.arch1)
        painter.end()
        self.label.setPixmap(pix)
```